# string to integer function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, x-editable

I'm developing a site, in this site my customer can change his table_id but when i try to change it. It becomes 0 in the database. table_id column is integer in mysql. I guess my problem is right there but I couldn't solve it. I used X-editable to edit the table_id;

http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

My code is below..

```
echo 'Table name: <label id="rez1" >'.$row['table_id'].'</label>';

<script>
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rez1').editable({
        name: 'table_id',
        type: 'text',
        pk: 1,
        url: 'main.php',
        title: 'Enter username'
    });
});
</script>

<?php
    $id= $_POST['pk'];
    $table_id= (int)$_POST['name'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE rezervasyon SET table_id='".$table_id."' WHERE rez_id='".$id."'");
?>
```

Comment: in your javascript, you just have `name` set to a hardcoded string value of `'table_id'` not an actual number... perhaps you meant to do something like `$('#rez1').html()` ?

Comment: Your code is extremely vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. For the sake of your users and yourself, please use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php script should be like below:

```
<?php
     $id= $_POST['pk'];
     $table_id= $_POST['value'];
     mysql_query("UPDATE rezervasyon SET table_id='".$table_id."' WHERE rez_id='".$id."'");
?>
```

And i don't what you're trying to do but when you post something try to use:

```
 if($_POST) {
       //your code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear to me but I think you are looking for

```
$table_id= (int)$_POST['table_id'];
```